# Proper usage of "themselves"?

Tags: pronouns, reflexives, emphasis

Could anyone please tell me if I used "themselves" properly in this sentences:

> Such artificial samples can also potentially reduce distortions ... that are due to varying properties of the samples *themselves*.

I'm not a native speaker but my sprachgefühl tells me that there should be this "themselves" at the end of the sentence -- can't really tell why though. If this is wrong, please let me know how you can tell. Thanks!

Comment: _the actual samples_ works perhaps better

Comment: Don’t put a comma after “me” and before “that” there in English. This is not German.

Comment: Yes, the *themselves* should be there after *samples* at the end of the sentence. The sentence is grammatical. If you have similar questions, you could maybe ask on [ell.se]

Comment: @mplungjan How's that any better, or even the same as what the OP is trying to say?

Comment: @tchrist Do they "put a comma" in such a place in German?

Comment: @Kris They tend to put a comma before a clause, that starts with “that” (*dass*) no matter whether it is restrictive or not.

Comment: @Kris to me "themselves" sounds more like persons than samples

Comment: @tchrist Thanks, that was indeed my German mother tongue putting the comma there ;) (where it would belong if it was a German sentence, yes)

Comment: @mplungjan 'people or things': http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/themselves No issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that's fine. The 'themselves' in this context adds emphasis it was specifically the samples which were causing the distortions.